# How to access pixel location in webgl using javascript

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am drawing a reactangle using webgl in a canvas of 400*400 pixel size. I want to discard the rendering if pixel location.x>200;
That means I want something like the following

```
if(gl.pixellocation.x>200)
discard;
```

How can i access the pixel position? I assume there should be some GLSL functionality. Anyone knows?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, I would suggest changing the viewport, using a stencil, or adding a clip plane, since all of those will be more optimal. But you can do what you're asking directly using gl_FragCoord in the fragment shader https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)#Fragment_shader_inputs

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps